# Pytest not finding all flask routes

Tags: flask, pytest

When I run `python -m pytest` on `.` folder, I have a test failed when it shouldn't.

In **app.py**

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

**route.py** at the same folder:

```
from app import app

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def get_status():
    return "Hello World!", 200
```

and **tests/test_app.py**

```
import pytest
from app import app

@pytest.fixture
def client():
    app.config['TESTING'] = True
    with app.test_client() as client:
        yield client

def test_index(client):
    rv = client.get('/')
    assert rv.status_code == 200
```

I tried and have `tests/test_app.py::test_index - assert 404 == 200` but don't know why.

I did try define route function at the same file where I define `app`, it works and the test function pass. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to create structured flask application with separate routes is to use `Blueprint` class. You have to declare blueprint for every route file and register them in main `app.py` file.

**app.py**

```py
from flask import Flask
from route import route_blueprint

app = Flask(__name__)

app.register_blueprint(route_blueprint)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

**route.py**

```py
from flask import Blueprint

route_blueprint = Blueprint('route', __name__,)


@route_blueprint.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def get_status():
    return "Hello World!", 200
```

**tests/test_app.py** -
There's nothing changed in this file

```py
import pytest
from app import app


@pytest.fixture
def client():
    app.config['TESTING'] = True
    with app.test_client() as client:
        yield client


def test_index(client):
    rv = client.get('/')
    assert rv.status_code == 200
```

With that tests are passing and app is working properly.

Comment: I have asked and found a temporary solution that add `import route` at the top the test file. But your solution makes more sense, and ofcourse it works. Thanks for your help!!